# Unable to install anything on Ubuntu 17.10 due to libreoffice

Tags: dpkg, libreoffice

I upgraded Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 today. It gave me few errors while upgrading mentioning images `_helpimg.zip.dpkg-new`, `libreoffice` and 3-4 more. In last it prompted that upgraded with error.

Now I'm not able to install / update anything. It gives this error

```
unable to open '/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/images_helpimg.zip.dpkg-new':
Operation not permitted
```

I have already tried the following commands

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice* openoffice*
```

It gives

```
Package 'libreoffice-wiki-publisher' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1 :
      Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed  
   liblibreofficekitgtk :
      Depends: libreofficekit-data but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: libreoffice-gtk3 but it is not going to be installed
   python3-uno :
      Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Which tried to install but failed

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
28 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 15.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 292277 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) over (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/images_helpimg.zip.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Hence I tried to install it manually

```
$sudo gdebi  /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.4.2-
0ubuntu0.17.10.1_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Failed to satisfy all dependencies (broken cache)
```

Since it didn't help, I tried following

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
:
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-style-galaxy
 libreoffice-l10n-hi
 libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-calc
 libreoffice-l10n-ja
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
 libreofficekit-data
 libreoffice-style-elementary
 gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za
 libreoffice-style-tango
 gnome-menus
 libreoffice-gtk3
 libreoffice-style-breeze
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-pdfimport
 libreoffice-draw
 libreoffice-help-en-us
 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
 libreoffice-ogltrans
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-help-ja
 libreoffice-impress
 liblibreofficekitgtk
 libreoffice-help-hi
 libreoffice-math
 libreoffice-help-en-gb
 libreoffice-base-core
```

But nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I installed Synaptic Package Manager from Ubuntu Software Center which is basically GUI alternative for `apt-get`. It let me install all the packages which I was facing difficulty with in APT. So I installed libreoffice, python3, and python3-minimal. It solved my problem. Now I'm able to install other packages too.